# What's the difference between convolution and crosscorrelation?

Tags: convolution

What's the difference between convolution and crosscorrelation? So why do you use '-' for convolution and '+' for crosscorrelation? Why do we need the "time reversal on one of the inputs" when doing convolution?

Comment: The "endearing" behaviour this OP exhibited on this page (whose traces are mainly erased now) continued [on this other page](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/378706/).

Answer (score 13):

The meanings of convolution and cross-correlation are quite different.

To see what happens in a simple setting, consider some independent integer valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ with respective distributions $p=(p_n)_n$ and $q=(q_n)_n$. 
Then:

- The convolution $p\ast q$ is the distribution $s=(s_n)_n$ defined by $$s_n=\sum\limits_kp_kq_{n-k}=P[X+Y=n]$$ for every $n$. Thus, $p\ast q$ is the distribution of $X+Y$.
- The cross-correlation $p\circ q$ is the distribution $c=(c_n)_n$ defined by $$c_n=\sum\limits_kp_kq_{n+k}=P[Y-X=n]$$ for every $n$. Thus, $p\circ q$ is the distribution of $Y-X$.

To sum up, considered at the level of distributions of independent random variables, the composition $\ast$ acts as an addition while the composition $\circ$ acts as a difference.

Comment: I don't understand this. I'm (i) confused on the notation (p_n)_n (what do both subscript n do here), and (ii) what is big P - probability? Why does X+Y = n? Sorry for being dumb!

Comment: @Prof Re (i), $(p_n)_n$ is the archi classical notation for a *sequence* $(\ldots,p_{-2},p_{-1},p_0,p_1,p_2,\ldots)$ as opposed to a specific value $p_n$ for a specific index $n$. Re (ii) and (iii), sorry but your queries make little sense: "what is big P - probability?" ??? Well... yes, big-P denotes the probability (what else?). "Why does X+Y = n?" Does it? Recall that $X+Y$ is a random variable hence $A=\{X+Y=n\}$ is an event and $P[X+Y=n]$ stands for $P(A)$. Never saw the string of characters: `P[X=x]` even once in your life before?