# clarification asked for 'difference between convolution and crosscorrelation?'

Tags: convolution

I don't understand answer formulated in ways like this "Thus, $p\ast q$ is the distribution of $X+Y$.
The cross-correlation $p\circ q$ is the distribution $c=(c_n)_n$ defined by $c_n=\sum\limits_kp_kq_{n+k}=P[Y-X=n]$ for every $n$. Thus, $p\circ q$ is the distribution of $Y-X$."

Can someone explain this in an easier way?
See: [What's the difference between convolution and crosscorrelation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353272/whats-the-difference-between-convolution-and-crosscorrelation)

PS: By convolution I meant the type of convolution that is used in image and signal processing. Stuff like this: http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution.html#convolution_2d

Comment: I have deleted several non-constructive comments.

Comment: It would help to include what specifically confuses you about Did's answer and the linked website.  I think the website's explanation is quite clear, especially the [complete example](http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution2d_example.html) they carry out, so if you need further explanation I need to know what exactly you don't understand.

Answer (score -1):

You can think of convolution as "[flip and shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aConvolution3.PNG)". Order doesn't matter - convolving A with B is the same as convolving B with A.

Correlation is convolution but without the "flip". Order in this case is important - correlating A with B is **not** the same as correlating B with A